# How do I combine multiple CSV files into one excel files with different sheets using Python

Tags: python, csv, xlsxwriter

I am trying to combine multiple csv files into one excel file whereby each file is it’s own sheet in the xls file.

Below is a python script that can convert all csv files in a folder into there respective excel files.

```
   import os
   import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
"""with open('output.csv', "rt", encoding = 'UTF-8') as fin:
    with open('outputconvert.csv', "wt", encoding = 'UTF-8') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace(';',','))"""

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('testws')
    with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
    workbook.close()
```

It works fine, but is there a way I can expand it such that it can merge files into one file and each file is in a separate worksheet

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The parameter sheet_name is constant. To export to multiple worksheets, you need to specify a different name for each worksheet.
This is the tested solution:

```
workbook = Workbook('../your_path/joined.xlsx')
counter = 0
for csv_file in glob.glob(os.path.join('../your_path/', '*.csv')):
    sheet_name = 'Sheet_' + str(counter)
    counter += 1
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
    with open(csv_file, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dataframe for each csv file and copy it in one excel as individual sheet.

Please refer below link.

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html

Answer (score 0):

You are creating discrete xlxs files by doing this;

```
for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
```

Instead, you should create your file(Workbook object) outside of the for loop, just for once, and then create new sheet in the loop.

This should work

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
"""with open('output.csv', "rt", encoding = 'UTF-8') as fin:
    with open('outputconvert.csv', "wt", encoding = 'UTF-8') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace(';',','))"""

workbook = Workbook('name_your_file.xlsx')
for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('testws')
    with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

one can load the .csv files from a directory and combine them all into one .xlsx excel file using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
import glob
from pathlib import Path

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('fc15.xlsx') # Arbitrary output name
for csvfilename in all_filenames:

    # in case your locale settings use , instead of a dot
    txt = Path(csvfilename).read_text()
    txt = txt.replace(',', '.')

    text_file = open(csvfilename, "w")
    text_file.write(txt)
    text_file.close()
    
    print("Loading "+ csvfilename)
    df= pd.read_csv(csvfilename,sep=';', encoding='utf-8')

    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=os.path.splitext(csvfilename)[0])
    print("done")
writer.save()
print("task completed")
```