# python create one excel from selected files using path and read excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, path

I have a folder with 100 excel files. I just need 20 of them and I want to create one excel file with selected sheets (same sheets for all excel files).

I did the following:

```py
# Working directory
data_folder = Path("C:/Users/.../myfiles")

#My working files:
excel01 = data_folder / "excel01.xls"
excel02 = data_folder / "excel02.xls"
...
excel20 = data_folder / "excel20.xls"
```

How do I create the single excel file?

I tried with

```py
df = pd.read_excel ([excel01,excel02,...,excel20],sheet_name = ['sheet1','sheet2,'sheet3'], skiprows = 4)
```

but it's not working. Any suggestions or more efficient ways are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303984/how-do-i-combine-multiple-csv-files-into-one-excel-files-with-different-sheets-u/57304171#57304171

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `ExcelWriter` and send it as a parameter to `df.to_excel`

```
excels = [excel01, excel02, ...]

sheets = random.sample(range(1, 16), 3)

i = 1
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for excel in excels:
        for sheet in sheets:
            df = pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name=f'Sheet{sheet}')
            df.to_excel(writer, f'Sheet{i}')
            writer.save()
            i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I don't need all the sheets in the files, just 'sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3' (in random order). How do I modify the script?

Comment: @Matteo Update my answer to get 10 random excel files.

Comment: Sorry I meant sheets not files. Basically every excel file has 15 sheets and I only need three of them e.g sheet1, sheet 5, sheet12. How do I update your script? Thank you

Comment: @Matteo see updated code, this will select 3 random sheets from each file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [21, 22, 23, 24]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [31, 32, 33, 34]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```